# Combine three select queries?

Tags: mysql

I would like to combine these three sql queries

```
SELECT homeupload, COUNT(*) FROM link GROUP BY homeupload
SELECT mediaType, COUNT(*) FROM link GROUP BY mediaType
SELECT emailSub, COUNT(*) FROM link WHERE emailSub='1' GROUP BY emailSub
```

Into a single queries. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you have a ER or something similar showing the relationship of those tables?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I merge two MySQL queries into one?](//stackoverflow.com/q/584571/90527)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using UNION

```
SELECT homeupload, COUNT(*) FROM link GROUP BY homeupload
UNION 
SELECT mediaType, COUNT(*) FROM link GROUP BY mediaType
UNION 
SELECT emailSub, COUNT(*) FROM link WHERE emailSub='1' GROUP BY emailSub
```

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)